# How to merge two collections with a specific condition in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have Two collections `competences` and `coCompetences` those collections look like :

competence :

```
 ...
    {
      "id": 6,
      "category_id": 17,
      "user_id": 1,
      "objective_level": 4,
      "current_level": 4,
      "target_date": "2021-11-28",
      "obtained_date": "2022-10-14",
      "comment": "",
      "created_at": "2020-01-08 10:06:28",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-08 10:06:28",
      "name": null,
      "competenceName": "Hierarchy Building & BOM (Bill of Material)",
      "category": {
        "id": 17,
        "competence": "Hierarchy Building & BOM (Bill of Material)",
        "created_at": "2020-01-08 09:53:55",
        "updated_at": "2020-01-08 09:53:55",
        "wheel_id": 10
      }
    },
    {
...
```

coCompetences :

```
{
    "category": {
      "id": 12,
      "competence": "Criticality Analysis",
      "created_at": "2020-01-08 09:53:55",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-08 09:53:55",
      "wheel_id": 10
    },
    "user_id": 1,
    "competenceName": "Criticality Analysis",
    "category_id": 12,
    "objective_level": 0,
    "current_level": 0,
    "target_date": "2020-01-14",
    "obtained_date": "2020-01-14",
    "comment": ""
  },
```

I would like to push **only** `coCompetences` elements into `competences` where `coCompetences.category_id` are not exist in `competences.category_id`

in another way : add all `coCompetences` elements to `competences` except those where `coCompetences.category_id` already exists in `coCompetences`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to write code instead of you, algorithm will be enough, I hope.
simplest way

1. Take array Ids from first array, for example by pluck()
2. Filter second and return items that don't exist in first
3. push filtered data to first